# Query I am using to grab data in JSON file not working?

Tags: sql, json, hive, hiveql, hue

I have a json file that looks like this:

MY_TABLE.HEADER

> {"app"."hello","space"."123","profileid"."aacc","date"."2020-10-10"}
> {"app"."island","space"."533","profileid"."xxyy","date"."2021-12-10"}
> {"app"."city","space"."883","profileid"."bcee","date"."2021-12-11"}

I want to just grab the list of profileid. So something that looks like this:

```
aacc
xxyy
bcee
```

I am using this query:

```
SELECT x.profileid
FROM MY_TABLE a
LATERAL VIEW JSON_TUPLE (
a.header,
'profileid'
)x as profileid
```

This is not working and I am getting this error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: UDFArgumentException json_tuple()'s arguments have to be string type
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What is the type of a.header ?  exception suggests it is not  string. Any chance it ia a STRUCT or MAP type? Tested with your strings, it works without exceptions, though JSON is not valid one and it does not extract values.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that your json is not valid one, it contains dots instead of `:`. You can fix it using regaxp_replace:

```
lateral view json_tuple(regexp_replace(a.header, '"\\."','":"'), 'profileid') x as profileid
```